# Adding a new annotator in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, annotations, stanford-nlp

I am trying to add a new annotator in Stanford CoreNLP according to the instructions in http://nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/corenlp.shtml.

"Adding a new annotator
`StanfordCoreNLP` also has the capacity to add a new annotator by reflection without altering the code in `StanfordCoreNLP.java`. To create a new annotator, extend the class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotator and define a constructor with the signature (String, Properties). Then, add the property customAnnotatorClass.`FOO=BAR` to the properties used to create the pipeline. If FOO is then added to the list of annotators, the class BAR will be created, with the name used to create it and the properties file passed in. "

I have created a new class for my new annotator, but i cannot put the properties file that would pass in.
I have only put the new annotator in the pipeline.

```
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, regexner, color");
props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.color", "myPackage.myPipeline");
```

Is there any example code to help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can have mine, if you like. The interesting stuff starts at `// adding our own annotator property`:

```
/** Annotates a document with our customized pipeline.
 * @param text A text to process
 * @return The annotated text
 */
private Annotation annotateText(String text) {
    Annotation doc = new Annotation(text);

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization,
    // NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // alternative: wsj-bidirectional
    try {
        props.put(
                "pos.model",
                "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/wsj-bidirectional/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // adding our own annotator property
    props.put("customAnnotatorClass.sdclassifier",
            "edu.kit.ipd.alicenlp.ivan.analyzers.StaticDynamicClassifier");

    // configure pipeline
    props.put(
                "annotators", 
                "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sdclassifier");
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    pipeline.annotate(doc);
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: How did you create your annotator?

Comment: Can you details the process/steps of creating a custom annotator for Stanford CoreNLP? Thanks

Comment: If you had asked me four years ago, I might have been able to help. But my code is still online. Maybe you want to check it out: https://svn.ipd.kit.edu/trac/AliceNLP/browser/ivan/trunk/src/main/java/edu/kit/ipd/alicenlp/ivan/analyzers/StaticDynamicClassifier.java