# Swapping in Berkley parser in Stanford corenlp

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I was using stanford nlp stack in my experiment and it was working nice until stanford PCFG parser started behaving weird for some of the sentences. I found http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html the berkley parser giving correct parse tree for the sentences in my dataset. How could i swap in stanford pos tagger by bekley parser and continue using stanford dependency parser. I found here http://brenocon.com/blog/2011/09/end-to-end-nlp-packages/ that it could be done, but not sure how.

Thanks in advance

---

I have used following configuration for this purpose:

```
    props.put("parse.type","charniak");
    props.put("parse.executable","src/main/resources/berkeley.bat");
    props.put("parse.model","");

    /*File: berkeley.bat*/

    @ECHO OFF
    java -jar C:\Users\Arindam\Downloads\berkeleymy.jar -gr C:/Users/Arindam/Downloads/eng_sm6.gr  -inputFile %4  -maxLength 399 -sentence_likelihood -kbest 2
```

Comment: Can you be more specific: what is the exact pipeline you want to have? What is your current list of annotators in CoreNLP that you want to modify?

Comment: i wanted to have pos,lemmatization,ner,parse,dcoref in my pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficult but clean way to do this would be to build your own annotator which hooks into a programmatic API of the Berkeley parser. You'd basically want to imitate the behavior of the [`ParserAnnotator`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotator.java), replacing the references to the Stanford `ParserQuery` implementation with references to Berkeley Parser + code that makes the necessary transformations.

Then using the results returned by the Berkeley Parser (transformed into the Stanford framework), you can use [`EnglishGrammaticalStructure`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/EnglishGrammaticalStructure.html) to convert the Berkeley constituency parse to dependency trees.

---

The less clean but perhaps easier way would be to have the Berkeley parser output a PTB-format parse, and use [the main method of `EnglishGrammaticalStructure`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalStructure.html#main-java.lang.String:A-) to generate from this CoNLL-format dependency parses.

---

More information on the first option, as requested:

You should make your own annotator which composes with / subclasses [`ParserAnnotator`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotator.java). The key method to override is [`ParserAnnotator#doOneSentence`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotator.java#L205). Here you can call out to the Berkeley Parser API, parse its results, and call [`ParserAnnotator#finishSentence`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotator.java#L244) with the properly converted tree. `finishSentence` should take care of putting the correct annotations in place for you.

You can easily hook in your custom annotator on the main pipeline using a special property. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20127276/176075) for example code (I'm referring to the `customAnnotatorClass` property).

Comment: I was browsing the code and came up with the solution mentioned above. It's working now but not sure it's a hack or not.

Comment: Ha, it is a bit of a hack—this is obviously not what the `CharniakParser` was built for—but it's nice that it works!

Comment: Hi, Jon could you please give me some more info on first method? 
Thank you .

Comment: OK, added some info. Good luck!

Comment: @CSStudent - did you eventually implemented the "clean" way of integration? Any experience (or code) the share?
@JonGauthier - would the sentiment (and other) annotators still work as is (`CoreNlp') with the Berkley parser instead of the Stanford one?

Comment: I did using a 'hacky' way and that worked for me. I will try to share the code today.